# JavaScript dynamic function name

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically assign the name of a function to an element of an associative array. This is my attempt which does not work.  The problem I am asking for help with is here where I try to call the function: `cr['cmd1'](x)`;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cr =[];
        var x = 5;
        cr['cmd1'] ='foo';
        var msg = cr['cmd1'](x);  
        alert(msg);

        function foo(y){
            return y;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I being passed a string here `cr['cmd1'] ='foo';` that I cannot control. That is why I have to work with a string as a starting point from an external application.

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the error? What are you expecting the alert results to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the functions using this syntax `window[function_name]('para1');`

Your usage will be something like this

```
var msg = window[cr['cmd1']](x);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to store it as a function, pass the function directly.  Otherwise, if you just want to store it as a string, then you can use the quotes.

Change:

```
cr['cmd1'] ='foo';
```

To:

```
cr['cmd1'] = foo;
```

Comment: Kirk, thanks, but I am being passed a string "foo" as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I would use window[] and make sure its a function before trying to execute it since you don't have control over what is passed.

```
var f = window[cr['cmd1']];
if(typeof f==='function') {
  f(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there is assigning a function to an array.  A more common pattern that you are probably trying to do is to call a function on an object with the array notation.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cr = {};
        cr.cmd1 = function foo(y){
            return y;
        };
        var x = 5;
        var msg = cr['cmd1'](x);  
        alert(msg);
    </script>
```

This code results in an alert box that contains the number 5.