# How to dynamically attach a function to an object

Tags: javascript, function, object, dynamic

*I know there are a few similar questions already on `SO` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419538/javascript-dynamic-function-name), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644246/javascript-dynamically-attaching-functions-to-objects)) but unfortunately my limited knowledge of `JS` doesn't allow me to extrapolate the scenarios to my personal use case, hence this question.*

I have the following piece of code which allows me to dynamically attach to and call from an object some functions, which works fine ([available on `JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/DHPHB/3/)):

**JavaScript**:

```
$.extend(true, window, {
    "MyPlugin": {
        "dynamicFunction": dummy_function
     }                
});

function dummy_function() {

}

function real_function(string) {
    alert(string);
}

function dynamic_call(function_name, text) {
    MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"] = eval(function_name);
    MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"](text);
}​
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onClick="dynamic_call('real_function','some text');">click me</button>​
```

**UPDATE:**

Funny enough, I was trying to replicate an issue I have whereby my function is scoped locally, but I ended writing an example where it isn't  :) (I told you `JS` isn't my thing). Therefore all `window[function_name]` answers are correct, although I accepted `James Allardice`'s because he extrapolated to the issue I was trying to resolve but didn't raise.

**How can I achieve the same functionality without the use of `eval`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function declarations in the global scope become properties of `window`, so you can use square bracket syntax:

```
function dynamic_call(function_name, text) {
    MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"] = window[function_name];
    MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"](text);
}​
```

If your function is not in the global scope, you could make it the value of a property of some object:

```
var myFuncs = {
    real_function: function () {
        alert(string);
    }
};
```

Then you can simply use:

```
MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"] = myFuncs[function_name];
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this without `eval` if the function is scoped locally. You can only do it without `eval` if the function is property of some object. This includes global object, so global functions can be done without `eval`.

With a global function or function that is property of some object:

```
MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"] = window[function_name];//window references global object
```

Answer (score 1):

If `real_function` is a gloabl function, you just call

```
window[function_name](text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the exact question, but if you can just pass in the function as a parameter, like this:

```
<button onClick="dynamic_call(real_function,'some text');">click me</button>​

function dynamic_call(f, text) {
   MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"] = f;
   MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"](text);
}​
```

Comment: this is the best solution. there's no reason to pass a string when you can just pass the function.

Comment: Couldn't cover everything with my example: I cannot pass the function name as a parameter, I get the function name from some HTML attribute value. Thanks but doesn't apply to my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `eval`, reference `function_name` from the `window` object:

```
MyPlugin["dynamicFunction"] = window[function_name];
```